# Send console output to a log file

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

I have an application written in Java and slf4j-logback for logging. There is so many System.out.println() statements in the application. Is there any way to write all the sysout output to separate log file using logback.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-bash/637839

Comment: Conceptually, something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945537/how-to-set-output-stream-to-textarea/12945678#12945678) and [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241024/system-out-println-redirection-in-java/22241169#22241169)

Answer (score 1):

Please run the application from your console / command prompt and redirect the output to a file.

For eg HelloWorld is your class. All prints will be redirected to hello.txt file.

java HelloWorld >> hello.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File(path/to/yourfile)));
```

Comment: While technically create, it's a good idea to to continue to print to the stdout AS well as the file, it's a little complicated, but achievable ;)

Comment: Need some double quotes.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. See [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837).