# Write String that is outputted to the console and edit it

Tags: java

So I have a method that outputs to the console

E.g.

```
public static void printing(){
System.out.println("33.3");
}
```

When I call this method in main, it should output 33.3
I want to be able to intercept it before it appears on the console so I can manipulate the data and save it to a variable.

So I found this

[Redirect console output to string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708342/redirect-console-output-to-string-in-java)

But I have trouble understanding the concept. How can I save the output as String and not really print anything to the console in the end?

Comment: Are you looking for String.format(...)?  

See https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-formatter

Comment: Alternatively, see this post about intercepting System.out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247688/intercept-system-out-and-prepend-date-time-in-java

Comment: @RiaanNel No, looking to intercept System.out, thanks for the link, I will check it out